# Serialize object that contains a linq2sql object for StateServer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql, serialization

I am currently trying to serialize an object for a webproject that is hosted on a Server that uses SessionState = Stateserver.

I marked the object as `[Serializable]` but the object contains an object that is part of a LINQ2SQL DataContext. I already read that it is possible to serialize this one with the `DataContractSerializer` but where is the correct place to do that ?

Do I just need to implement `ISerializeable` and serialize my NodeObject inside the `GetObjectData()` Function and add it to the `SerializationInfo` ? Any one any ideas about a good approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it now. I marked my Objects that contain the Linqobject with `[Serializable]` and included the `ISerializable` Interface. `DBOItem` is my LinqObject

```
    public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
    {
        PropertyInfo[] infos = this.DBOItem.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach ( PropertyInfo pi in infos )
        {
            bool isAssociation = false;
            foreach ( object obj in pi.GetCustomAttributes( true ) )
            {
                if ( obj.GetType() == typeof( System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute ) )
                { isAssociation = true; break; }
            }
            if ( !isAssociation )
            {
                if ( pi.GetValue( this.DBOItem, null ) != null )
                {
                    info.AddValue( pi.Name, pi.GetValue( this.DBOItem, null ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Ctor that needs to be included for deserialisation looks like this :

```
protected BusinessObjectBase( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
{
    this.DBOItem = new T();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = this.DBOItem.GetType().GetProperties();
            SerializationInfoEnumerator enumerator = info.GetEnumerator();

            while ( enumerator.MoveNext() )
            {
                SerializationEntry se = enumerator.Current;
                foreach ( PropertyInfo pi in properties )
                {
                    if ( pi.Name == se.Name )
                    {
                        pi.SetValue( this.DBOItem, info.GetValue( se.Name, pi.PropertyType ), null );
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link. It will be helpful to understand the difference between [Serializable] VS DataContractSerializer. Please implement based on your suitability as there is not much difference in your projcet.

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/